# How to Name your Tables after the Sheet Names

Tags: excel, vba

I want to name my tables I'm creating in VBA according to the worksheet name they're on.

```
   With myTable
                .Name = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name
                .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
            End With
```

I get a run time error '424' which says "Object Required"

How do I have the tables I'm creating via previous code name the tables the same as the worksheet names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Parent` property to get the name of the worksheet (the parent object of a table).

```
With myTable
    .Name = .Parent.Name
End With
```

Comment: Thanks again Scott. Much appreciated